# Is there any method to find the products in the ReactJS cart?

Tags: reactjs

This is my addtocart function, i wanted an item to add in a cart if the item does not exist in the cart already. But if the item is already present in the cart it just increase quantity of that particular item. Unfortunately, it is giving the error that if i add the same item in the cart again it not only increase the quantity of that particular item but also append that item into the cart again which means it runs the `case false` also after running `case true`.So i dont want to run `case false`. Why it is giving such error?

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([])   
     const addCart = (id) =>{
                if(cart.length==0)
                {
                    const data = foodproducts.reduce((r, {_id,fcategory,fdata}) => {
                        let o = fdata.filter(({fid}) => fid.includes(id));
                        if(o && o.length)
                          r.push({_id,fcategory, fdata : [...o]});
                        return r;
                    },[]);
                    setCart([...cart, ...data])
                }
                else
                {
                cart.forEach(product =>
                    product.fdata.every(f=>{
                        switch(f.fid==id) {
                            case true:
                                
                                alert("Working true b")
                                cart.forEach(product =>
                                    product.fdata.every(f=>{
                                        if( f.fid == id)
                                    {
                                       f.count += 1;
                                    }
                                    }
                                        )  
                                       
                                )
                                setCart([...cart])
                                  alert("Item alreadt existed in the cart")
                              break;
                            case false:
                                alert("Working false b")
                                const data = foodproducts.reduce((r, {_id,fcategory,fdata}) => {
                                    let o = fdata.filter(({fid}) => fid.includes(id));
                                    if(o && o.length)
                                      r.push({_id,fcategory, fdata : [...o]});
                                    return r;
                                },[]);
                                setCart([...cart, ...data])
                              break;
                            default:
                              alert("Invalid")
                          }
                        
                })
                )          
            }
            }
```

This is my array data

```
{
        "_id":2,
        "fcategory": "Sandwich",
        "fdata":[
            {
                "fid" :"s1",
                "fname":"Classic Cheese Sandwich",
                "count": 1
            },
            {
                "fid" :"s2",
                "fname":"Plain Cheese Sandwich",
                "count": 1
            },
            
    ]
    },
```

Comment: For this line `let o = fdata.filter(({fid}) => fid.includes(id));`. Does fid contain more than one id?

Comment: you can see the array data above. I had just edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

I believe the issues stems from three things:

1. `addCart` is `forEach`ing over the cart data which means the same callback is called on each item in the cart. This means both `true` and `false` branches are executed when the item matches or doesn't match. This alone is ok, but when coupled with...
2. Using standard state updates in a loop. When you hit one of the `false` case iterations then the `fid` doesn't match and the item is appended to the end of the array. When enqueueing state updates in a loop and ***don't*** use a functional state update then each enqueued update uses the same state from the previous render cycle and the last update wins and is used for the next render cycle.
3. The single `true` branch iteration mutates the state object. `f.count += 1;` mutates the item count. This is why it appears as though the `true` branch ran *even though it was overwritten later by a `false` branch iteration*.

## Solution

1. `addCart` should first search by `fid` if the item is already in the cart.
2. Only add a new item to cart if not found.
3. Correctly update the food item object without mutation. This means shallow copying the cart array, but also shallow copying the food item, *then* updating the food item property.

`addCart` code:

```
const addCart = (fid) => {
  const itemIndex = cart.findIndex((item) => item.fid === fid);

  if (itemIndex === -1) {
    // Food item not found, add to cart
    const getItemByFid = (fid) =>
      foodproducts.reduce((data, { _id, fcategory, fdata }) => {
        const foodIndex = fdata.findIndex((item) => item.fid === fid);
        if (foodIndex !== -1) {
          return {
            _id,
            fcategory,
            ...fdata[foodIndex],
            count: 1
          };
        }
        return data;
      }, {});

    setCart((cart) => [...cart, getItemByFid(fid)]);
  } else {
    // Food item found, update item count in cart
    setCart((cart) =>
      cart.map((item) =>
        item.fid === fid
          ? {
              ...item,
              count: item.count + 1
            }
          : item
      )
    );
  }
};
```

[image: Edit is-there-any-method-to-find-the-products-in-the-reactjs-cart]

Full demo code:

```
const foodproducts = [
  {
    _id: 2,
    fcategory: "Sandwich",
    fdata: [
      {
        fid: "s1",
        fname: "Classic Cheese Sandwich",
        count: 1
      },
      {
        fid: "s2",
        fname: "Plain Cheese Sandwich",
        count: 1
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  const addCart = (fid) => {
    const itemIndex = cart.findIndex((item) => item.fid === fid);

    if (itemIndex === -1) {
      const getItemByFid = (fid) =>
        foodproducts.reduce((data, { _id, fcategory, fdata }) => {
          const foodIndex = fdata.findIndex((item) => item.fid === fid);
          if (foodIndex !== -1) {
            return {
              _id,
              fcategory,
              ...fdata[foodIndex],
              count: 1
            };
          }
          return data;
        }, {});

      setCart((cart) => [...cart, getItemByFid(fid)]);
    } else {
      setCart((cart) =>
        cart.map((item) =>
          item.fid === fid
            ? {
                ...item,
                count: item.count + 1
              }
            : item
        )
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <div>
        {foodproducts.flatMap(({ fdata }) =>
          fdata.map(({ fid, fname }) => (
            <div key={fid}>
              {fname}{" "}
              <button type="button" onClick={() => addCart(fid)}>
                Add
              </button>
            </div>
          ))
        )}
      </div>

      <div>
        Cart:
        {cart.map(({ fid, fname, count }) => (
          <div key={fid}>
            {fname} ... {count}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank-you Drew Reese, it solved my issue. Thanks alot !

Comment: Drew Reese can you please help me in sorting out a problem in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65777121/is-there-any-method-to-filter-the-axios-data-in-reactjs